# Managing multiple composites with one window in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I just started using SWT in eclipse. Right now I'm using Hibernate to connect to a database and retrieve the required information on to a composite. The views includes one SWT application window and several composites. How would I place these composites based on what button a user clicks on? Since the composite needs to be put on the main window, should I have a reference to the main window in each composite?

Also the main window is completely empty. What the user would click on would be one of the buttons in one of the composites. Should I have just one controller? But then each of the composites have buttons which needs to open up other composites on the main window. Should I have controllers for each of these composites? 
Am I going in the wrong direction? Any help would be great.

Thanks

**EDIT :** An example of what I am trying to do.
I have a main window and 3 composites : A, B, C;
Each of these composites has buttons which can take the user to the other 2 composites by replacing the current composite on the main window.

So, should I have a controller for each composite or just the main window?
Also to add a composite to the main window, do I need to have a reference to the main window in each of these composites?

[image]

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're asking for. Could you maybe generate a mockup image that shows what you want?

Comment: @Baz Unforunately I need 10 reputation points to post images. Can I take an example and explain what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can add the link to the image and we can add it for you. Just upload it to some image host.

Comment: @Baz http://postimg.org/image/l8zu4uc2j/

Comment: @baz Upvoting OP's question would have given him the needed rep to post the image. Here you are, amitabh.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am aware of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is technically quite similar to the Wizard UI. The idea is to add all your Composites to the main window, but have only one *visible* at a time. This will probably work with the `FillLayout`. You will also probably need to call `layout()` and `redraw()` on the main window after changing the visibility of the components.

Comment: I just tried it out. Works perfectly! BTW I want to try and keep the back end logic out of the front end since there are a few other people working on it as well. So should I use separate controllers for each of the composites?

Comment: I was thinking about that part of your question as well, but I don't have a one-size-fits-all answer. Try the simpler approach and see if you have issues with it. BTW having your front end talk directly to the DB is not how things are done these days---you would typically have a server-side Java application between the front end and the DB.

Comment: So I'll move my Hibernate code to the server and access it through the  desktop app?

Comment: Yes, typically using REST web services. It's more architectural work, but gives you proper connection pooling, central deployment of business logic, minimizing public Internet traffic (whenever you need to fetch more from the DB to derive the data you are really interested in), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use StackLayout for these screens.

Create a main Composite with StackLayout, setup each screen as a child of the main composite. Use an empty Composite as a first screen.

See [StackLayout usage examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/2000__StackLayout.htm)